# How to concatenate two array by using two request in javascript with mailchimp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

The title may not very clear. I'm gonna explain my problem.

Here is my code:

```
mailchimpMarketing = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimpMarketing.setConfig({
apiKey: "MY API KEY",
server: "MY SERVER",
});

const getEmailMembersFromList = async (listID, offset , count) => {
  const response = await mailchimpMarketing.lists.getListMembersInfo(listID, {offset, count});
    emails = response.members.map(member => {
      return member.email_address
    })
  console.log(emails)
}

getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 0, 1000)
getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 1000, 58)
```

It display in the terminal two arrays of emails addresses. I have to make two calls because there is more than 1000 emails addresses (1058 in total) and the maximum is 1000.

Now I want to concatenate those two array, maybe with the `.concat()` method but I don't know how to do it in my case.

EDIT 1

```
mailchimpMarketing = require("@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing");

mailchimpMarketing.setConfig({
apiKey: "MY API KEY",
server: "MY SERVER",
});

const getEmailMembersFromList = async (listID, offset , count) => {
  const response = await mailchimpMarketing.lists.getListMembersInfo(listID, {offset, count});
    emails = response.members.map(member => {
      return member.email_address
    })
  //console.log(emails)
  return emails
}

getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 0, 1000)
getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 1000, 58)
```

Comment: have you tried =>  
let list = getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 0, 1000);
list.concat(getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 0, 1000));

Comment: Yes and it said that .concat is not a function. That's strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
let result = [];

const getEmailMembersFromList = async (listID, offset, count) => {
  await mailchimpMarketing.lists
    .getListMembersInfo(listID, { offset, count })
    .then((response) => {
      emails = response.members.map((member) => {
        return member.email_address;
      });
      // try using spread operator, hopefully it should work
      result = [...result, ...emails];
    });
};

getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 0, 1000);
getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 1000, 58);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Same as Reyno answer, it work because it put my two array in an other array but I want my two array to merge in one. This code give me this [ [dataOfFirstRequest] [dataOfSecondRequest] ] and I want this [ dataOfFirstRequest, dataOfSecondRequest ]

Comment: something like this: [[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8]] ?

Comment: Yes that's what I get when I use your code and I want something like this: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

Comment: you can use flat method for that. like : let a = [[1,2,3,4][5,6,7,8]].flat() it will return [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: you can also use the spread operator for that, I have updated the answer, please check if it works.

Comment: It doesn't work, it said that .flat is not a function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222973/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-samyrharade).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222976/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-samy-rharade).

Answer (score 0):

Since `async` functions always return a promise you could add all requests into an array and use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to get all the data.

FYI: you are not returning anything from your `getEmailMembersFromList` function which is necessary to get it to work.

Example:

```
const firstGroup = getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 0, 1000);
const secondGroup = getEmailMembersFromList("MY LIST ID", 1000, 58);

Promise.all([firstGroup, secondGroup]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

Comment: Ok but it display one array with my two array inside and I just want one array with all of my emails addresses inside

Comment: But now I put a return in my getEmailMembersFromList function, I'm gonna edit my post

Comment: Why I can't do finalGroup = firstGroup.concat(secondGroup) ?